# Mocking OAuth2 client with WebTestClient for servlet applications results in null httpHandlerBuilder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My Spring Boot application acts as an OAuth2 client by using the `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` dependency.

Now I'd like to write an integration test (`@SpringBootTest`) to verify the behavior of a REST endpoint secured by OAuth2. The [Testing OAuth 2.0 Clients documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/test/web/oauth2.html#webflux-testing-oauth2-client) describes that it is possible to use `mutateWith(mockOAuth2Client())` to mock a login via OAuth2.

```java
public class UserIT {

  @Autowired
  private WebTestClient webTestClient;

  @Test
  void test() {
    webTestClient
      .mutateWith(mockOAuth2Client("keycloak"))
      .get()
      .uri("/api/user/1345")
      .exchange()
      .expectStatus().isOk();
  }
}
```

However, the test fails with the following message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.server.adapter.WebHttpHandlerBuilder.filters(java.util.function.Consumer)" because "httpHandlerBuilder" is null
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.reactive.server.SecurityMockServerConfigurers$OAuth2ClientMutator.afterConfigurerAdded(SecurityMockServerConfigurers.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClientBuilder.apply(DefaultWebTestClientBuilder.java:265)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient.mutateWith(DefaultWebTestClient.java:167)
```

As far as I have understood it, this `WebTestClient` setup is only suitable for "Reactive Applications" whereas my application is a "Servlet Application". Unfortunately, I cannot find the necessary information how to mock this OAuth2 client for a servlet application.

Comment: You can't inject that null object in your test configuration? i.e. create it in the appropriate spring bean...

Comment: There is a _non reactive_ section for [Mocking OAuth2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/oauth2.html) which may reduce some friction when writing tests.

Comment: @mana As far as I understand, this section only applies when using `MockMvc`, not `WebTestClient`.

Comment: Absolutely, I've also tried this (this is what brought me here :) and failed. It feels like there is `mockMvc` which is designated for the classic (non-reactive) version (`spring-boot-starter-web`); and there is `webTestClient` which is designated for reactive applications (relies on `spring-boot-starter-webflux` or project reactor). Let me know, if there is a way!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run your exact `@Autowired` and `@Test` code successfully with the following test configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebTestClient webTestClient(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        return WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(applicationContext).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this annotation to the test class helps: @AutoConfigureWebTestClient